# Linking css in twig

Tags: css, twig

I'm trying to link css in my twig template. But it is not working.
I have used following:

```
<link href="../../vendor/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But it is not working.
Can anyone tell me what should i do? I've tried using asset and url functions, but it gives function not found exception.

Comment: please add your code, is not visible

Comment: Does the page with your showed code extend another twig file?

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework? If you are running an application with asset path in the root, then you can remove ../../ and just update with /vendor/style.css

Comment: @aendeerei no it is the base file

Comment: @Nikhil No i'm creating my own mvc framework.

Comment: @Anon Since we are not familiar with your folder structure, it's difficult to identify the exact issue. It will help if you can add more details about the framework to the question.

Comment: why don't you use an absolute url?